Click Event Duplication Issue in Kanban Application
I'm developing a Kanban application using JavaScript and I'm facing an issue with the duplication of click events. The problem occurs when I try to add a new item to the Kanban. The click event on the save button seems to be registered multiple times, resulting in multiple fetch requests when the button is clicked.
Here's a summary of what I'm doing:

I have a save button inside an offcanvas that is displayed when the user clicks to add a new item.
I'm using addEventListener to add a click event to the save button.
Before adding the event, I'm removing any existing click event using removeEventListener.

Despite this, the click event is still being duplicated infinity, resulting in multiple requests.
Additionally, I'm intentionally forcing a fetch error to simulate a scenario where not all fields are filled out. This is done to test the error handling logic.
Here, I forced the POST request without any client input, only three times. However, you can see that my code sends six fetch requests to my API. Each request is duplicated. The first one is singular, but starting from the first, they begin to duplicate.

Apparently my problem is here:
Client
const kanban = new jKanban({
    element: '.kanban-wrapper',
    gutter: '10px', // Ajuste o valor para o espaçamento desejado
    widthBoard: '250px',
    dragItems: true,
    boards: boards,
    dragBoards: true,
    addItemButton: true,
    buttonContent: '⚒️ Adicionar Nova Tarefa',
    itemAddOptions: {
      enabled: true,
      content: '⚒️ Adicionar Nova Tarefa',
      class: 'kanban-title-button btn btn-default text-heading fw-normal shadow-none text-capitalize',
      footer: false
    },
    click: function (el) {
      let element = el;
      let title = element.getAttribute('data-eid')
        ? element.querySelector('.kanban-text').textContent
        : element.textContent,
        date = element.getAttribute('data-due-date'),
        dateObj = new Date(),
        year = dateObj.getFullYear(),
        dateToUse = date
          ? date + ', ' + year
          : dateObj.getDate() + ' ' + dateObj.toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long' }) + ', ' + year,
        label = element.getAttribute('data-badge-text'),
        avatars = element.getAttribute('data-assigned');

      // Mostrar offcanvas do Kanban
      kanbanOffcanvas.show();

      // Obter dados na sidebar
      kanbanSidebar.querySelector('#title').value = title;
      kanbanSidebar.querySelector('#due-date').nextSibling.value = dateToUse;

      // ! Usando método jQuery para obter sidebar devido à dependência do select2
      $('.kanban-update-item-sidebar').find(select2).val(label).trigger('change');

      // Remover e atualizar atribuídos
      kanbanSidebar.querySelector('.assigned').innerHTML = '';
      kanbanSidebar
        .querySelector('.assigned')
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          'afterbegin',
          renderAvatar(avatars, false, 'sm', '2', el.getAttribute('data-members')) +
          "<div class='avatar avatar-sm ms-2'>" +
          "<span class='avatar-initial rounded-circle bg-label-secondary'><i class='ri-add-line'></i></span>" +
          '</div>'
        );
    },

    buttonClick: async function (el, boardId) {
      try {
        addItemOffcanvas.show();

        // Esperar o usuário preencher e submeter o formulário
        const saveButton = addItemSidebar.querySelector('.save-button');
        saveButton.addEventListener('click', async function () {
          const title = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-title').value;
          const due_date = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-due-date').value;
          const badge_text = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-label').value;
          const badge_color = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-label option:checked').dataset.color.replace('bg-label-', '');
          const members = Array.from(addItemSidebar.querySelector('#assigned-select').selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);
          const comments_data = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-comments').value;
          const response = await fetch('/kanban/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              boardId,
              title,
              comments_data: comments_data || [],
              badge_text: badge_text || [],
              badge_color: badge_color || [],
              due_date: due_date || '',
              members: members || []
            })
          });

          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Erro ao adicionar o item');
          }

          const newItem = await response.json();
          showNotification('success', 'Item adicionado com sucesso', 5000);

          kanban.addElement(boardId, {
            title: "<span class='kanban-text'>" + newItem.title + '</span>',
            id: newItem.id,
            comments_data: newItem.comments_data,
            badge_text: newItem.badge_text,
            badge_color: newItem.badge_color,
            due_date: newItem.due_date,
            members: newItem.members
          });

          // Fechar o offcanvas após adicionar o item
          addItemOffcanvas.hide();
        });

      } catch (error) {
        showNotification('danger', 'Erro ao adicionar o item', 5000);
      }
    }
  });

Server:
router.post('/add', authTokenMiddleware, rateLimiter, [
  body('boardId').isString().trim().escape().isLength({ max: 50 }).notEmpty(),
  body('title').isString().trim().escape().isLength({ max: 100 }).notEmpty(),
  body('comments_data').notEmpty().isString().trim().escape().isLength({ max: 500 }).customSanitizer(removeEmojis),
  body('badge_text').notEmpty().isString().trim().escape().isLength({ max: 50 }),
  body('badge_color').notEmpty().isString().trim().escape().isLength({ max: 20 }),
  body('due_date').notEmpty().isISO8601().toDate(),
  body('members').notEmpty().isArray(),
  handleValidationErrors
], async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Iniciando rota POST /add');
  try {
    const { boardId, title, comments_data, badge_text, badge_color, due_date, members } = req.body;

    console.log('Dados recebidos:', { boardId, title, comments_data, badge_text, badge_color, due_date, members });

    const newItem = {
      id: `${boardId}-${Date.now()}`,
      title,
      comments_data,
      badge_text,
      badge_color,
      due_date,
      members,
      activity_log: []
    };

    console.log('Novo item criado:', newItem);

    let board = await Kanban.findOne({ id: boardId });
    if (board) {
      console.log('Board encontrado:', board.id);
      if (!board.item) {
        console.log('Array de itens não existe, criando novo');
        board.item = [];
      }
      board.item.push(newItem);
    } else {
      console.log('Board não encontrado, criando novo');
      board = new Kanban({
        id: boardId,
        title: " Edite Meu Nome",
        item: [newItem]
      });
    }
    await board.save();
    console.log('Item salvo com sucesso');
    res.status(201).json(newItem);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao adicionar item:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ type: 'danger', message: 'Erro ao adicionar item' });
  }
});

Full Code:
/**
 * App Kanban
 */

'use strict';

(async function () {
  // ==========================
  // Variables and DOM Elements
  // ==========================
  let boards;
  const kanbanSidebar = document.querySelector('.kanban-update-item-sidebar'),
    kanbanWrapper = document.querySelector('.kanban-wrapper'),
    commentEditor = document.querySelector('.comment-editor'),
    datePicker = document.querySelector('#due-date'),
    select2 = $('.select2'), // Using jQuery variables due to select2 dependency
    assetsPath = '/assets/';

  // ==========================
  // Offcanvas Initialization
  // ==========================
  const kanbanOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(kanbanSidebar);
  const addItemSidebar = document.querySelector('.kanban-add-item-sidebar');
  const addItemOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(addItemSidebar);

  // ==========================
  // Kanban Data Request
  // ==========================
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/kanban/data');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Error fetching Kanban data');
    }
    boards = await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Kanban data:', error);
  }

  // ==========================
  // Component Initialization
  // ==========================
  // Datepicker
  if (datePicker) {
    datePicker.flatpickr({
      monthSelectorType: 'static',
      altInput: true,
      altFormat: 'j F, Y',
      dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'
    });
  }

  // Select2
  if (select2.length) {
    function renderLabels(option) {
      if (!option.id) {
        return option.text;
      }
      var $badge = "<div class='badge " + $(option.element).data('color') + " rounded-pill'> " + option.text + '</div>';
      return $badge;
    }

    select2.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      select2Focus($this);
      $this.wrap("<div class='position-relative'></div>").select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Label',
        dropdownParent: $this.parent(),
        templateResult: renderLabels,
        templateSelection: renderLabels,
        escapeMarkup: function (es) {
          return es;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Comment Editor
  if (commentEditor) {
    new Quill(commentEditor, {
      modules: {
        toolbar: '.comment-toolbar'
      },
      placeholder: 'Write a Comment... ',
      theme: 'snow'
    });
  }

  // ==========================
  // Rendering Functions
  // ==========================
  function renderBoardDropdown() {
    return (
      "<div class='dropdown'>" +
      "<i class='dropdown-toggle ri-more-2-line ri-20px cursor-pointer' id='board-dropdown' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'></i>" +
      "<div class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end' aria-labelledby='board-dropdown'>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item delete-board' href='javascript:void(0)'> <i class='ri-delete-bin-7-line'></i> <span class='align-middle'>Delete</span></a>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item' href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='ri-edit-2-line'></i> <span class='align-middle'>Rename</span></a>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item' href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='ri-archive-line'></i> <span class='align-middle'>Archive</span></a>" +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }

  function renderDropdown() {
    return (
      "<div class='dropdown kanban-tasks-item-dropdown'>" +
      "<i class='dropdown-toggle ri-more-2-line ri-20px text-muted' id='kanban-tasks-item-dropdown' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'></i>" +
      "<div class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end' aria-labelledby='kanban-tasks-item-dropdown'>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item' href='javascript:void(0)'>Copy task link</a>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item' href='javascript:void(0)'>Duplicate task</a>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item delete-task' href='javascript:void(0)'>Delete</a>" +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }

  function renderHeader(color, text) {
    return (
      "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap align-items-center mb-2'>" +
      "<div class='item-badges d-flex'> " +
      "<div class='badge rounded-pill bg-label-" +
      color +
      "'> " +
      text +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      renderDropdown() +
      '</div>'
    );
  }

  function renderAvatar(images, pullUp, size, margin, members) {
    var $transition = pullUp ? ' pull-up' : '',
      $size = size ? 'avatar-' + size + '' : '',
      member = members == undefined ? ' ' : members.split(',');

    return images == undefined
      ? ' '
      : images
        .split(',')
        .map(function (img, index, arr) {
          var $margin = margin && index !== arr.length - 1 ? ' me-' + margin + '' : '';

          return `<div class='avatar ${$size}${$margin} avatar-shadow' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-placement='top' title='${member[index]}'><img src='/assets/img/avatars/${img}.jpg' alt='Avatar' class='rounded-circle ${$transition}' style='object-fit: cover; object-position: center top;'></div>`;
        })
        .join(' ');
  }

  function renderFooter(comments_data, members, due_date) {
    // Calculate the difference in days between the current date and the due date
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const dueDate = new Date(due_date);
    const timeDiff = dueDate - currentDate;
    const dayDiff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    // Determine the color class based on the day difference
    let colorClass;
    if (dayDiff < 3) {
      colorClass = 'text-danger'; // Red
    } else if (dayDiff < 5) {
      colorClass = 'text-orange'; // Orange
    } else if (dayDiff < 7) {
      colorClass = 'text-warning'; // Yellow
    } else {
      colorClass = 'text-success'; // Green
    }

    return (
      "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap mt-2'>" +
      "<div class='d-flex align-items-center'>" +
      `<span class='due-date me-3'><i class='ri-calendar-event-line'></i> <span class='${colorClass}'>` + formatDate(due_date) + "</span></span>" +
      "<span class='align-middle me-3'><i class='ri-wechat-line ri-20px me-1'></i>" +
      '<span> ' +
      comments_data.length +
      ' </span>' +
      '</span>' +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='avatar-group d-flex align-items-center assigned-avatar'>" +
      renderAvatar(members, true, 'xs', null, members) +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }

  function formatDate(date) {
    if (!date) return '';
    
    // Create a Date object from the date string
    const dateObj = new Date(date);
    
    // Extract year, month, and day
    const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    const month = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // Month is 0-indexed
    const day = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    
    // Return the date in the desired format
    return `${year.toString().slice(-2)}/${month}/${day}`;
  }

  // ==========================
  // Kanban Initialization
  // ==========================
  const kanban = new jKanban({
    element: '.kanban-wrapper',
    gutter: '10px', // Adjust the value for desired spacing
    widthBoard: '250px',
    dragItems: true,
    boards: boards,
    dragBoards: true,
    addItemButton: true,
    buttonContent: '⚒️ Add New Task',
    itemAddOptions: {
      enabled: true,
      content: '⚒️ Add New Task',
      class: 'kanban-title-button btn btn-default text-heading fw-normal shadow-none text-capitalize',
      footer: false
    },
    click: function (el) {
      let element = el;
      let title = element.getAttribute('data-eid')
        ? element.querySelector('.kanban-text').textContent
        : element.textContent,
        date = element.getAttribute('data-due-date'),
        dateObj = new Date(),
        year = dateObj.getFullYear(),
        dateToUse = date
          ? date + ', ' + year
          : dateObj.getDate() + ' ' + dateObj.toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long' }) + ', ' + year,
        label = element.getAttribute('data-badge-text'),
        avatars = element.getAttribute('data-assigned');

      // Show Kanban offcanvas
      kanbanOffcanvas.show();

      // Get data in the sidebar
      kanbanSidebar.querySelector('#title').value = title;
      kanbanSidebar.querySelector('#due-date').nextSibling.value = dateToUse;

      // Using jQuery method to get sidebar due to select2 dependency
      $('.kanban-update-item-sidebar').find(select2).val(label).trigger('change');

      // Remove and update assigned
      kanbanSidebar.querySelector('.assigned').innerHTML = '';
      kanbanSidebar
        .querySelector('.assigned')
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
          'afterbegin',
          renderAvatar(avatars, false, 'sm', '2', el.getAttribute('data-members')) +
          "<div class='avatar avatar-sm ms-2'>" +
          "<span class='avatar-initial rounded-circle bg-label-secondary'><i class='ri-add-line'></i></span>" +
          '</div>'
        );
    },

    buttonClick: async function (el, boardId) {
      try {
        addItemOffcanvas.show();

        // Wait for the user to fill and submit the form
        const saveButton = addItemSidebar.querySelector('.save-button');
        saveButton.addEventListener('click', async function () {
          const title = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-title').value;
          const due_date = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-due-date').value;
          const badge_text = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-label').value;
          const badge_color = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-label option:checked').dataset.color.replace('bg-label-', '');
          const members = Array.from(addItemSidebar.querySelector('#assigned-select').selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);
          const comments_data = addItemSidebar.querySelector('#add-comments').value;
          const response = await fetch('/kanban/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              boardId,
              title,
              comments_data: comments_data || [],
              badge_text: badge_text || [],
              badge_color: badge_color || [],
              due_date: due_date || '',
              members: members || []
            })
          });

          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Error adding item');
          }

          const newItem = await response.json();
          showNotification('success', 'Item added successfully', 5000);

          kanban.addElement(boardId, {
            title: "<span class='kanban-text'>" + newItem.title + '</span>',
            id: newItem.id,
            comments_data: newItem.comments_data,
            badge_text: newItem.badge_text,
            badge_color: newItem.badge_color,
            due_date: newItem.due_date,
            members: newItem.members
          });

          // Close the offcanvas after adding the item
          addItemOffcanvas.hide();
        });

      } catch (error) {
        showNotification('danger', 'Error adding item', 5000);
      }
    }
  });

  // ==========================
  // Scrollbar Initialization
  // ==========================
  if (kanbanWrapper) {
    new PerfectScrollbar(kanbanWrapper);
  }

  // ==========================
  // Custom Item Rendering
  // ==========================
  const kanbanContainer = document.querySelector('.kanban-container'),
    kanbanTitleBoard = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.kanban-title-board')),
    kanbanItem = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.kanban-item'));

  if (kanbanItem) {
    kanbanItem.forEach(function (el) {
      const element = "<span class='kanban-text'>" + el.textContent + '</span>';
      let img = '';
      if (el.getAttribute('data-image') !== null) {
        img =
          "<img class='img-fluid mb-2 rounded-3' src='" +
          assetsPath +
          'img/elements/' +
          el.getAttribute('data-image') +
          "'>";
      }
      el.textContent = '';
      if (el.getAttribute('data-badge_color') !== undefined && el.getAttribute('data-badge_text') !== undefined) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML(
          'afterbegin',
          renderHeader(el.getAttribute('data-badge_color'), el.getAttribute('data-badge_text')) + img + element
        );
      }
      if (
        el.getAttribute('data-comments_data') !== undefined ||
        el.getAttribute('data-due_date') !== undefined ||
        el.getAttribute('data-members') !== undefined
      ) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML(
          'beforeend',
          renderFooter(
            el.getAttribute('data-comments_data'),
            el.getAttribute('data-members'),
            el.getAttribute('data-due_date') // Pass the due date to the function
          )
        );
      }
    });
  }

  // ==========================
  // Tooltip Initialization
  // ==========================
  const tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
  tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
  });

  // ==========================
  // Interaction Events
  // ==========================
  // Prevent sidebar opening when clicking on task dropdown buttons
  const tasksItemDropdown = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.kanban-tasks-item-dropdown'));
  if (tasksItemDropdown) {
    tasksItemDropdown.forEach(function (e) {
      e.addEventListener('click', function (el) {
        el.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
  }

  // Debounce function to limit request frequency
  function debounce(func, wait) {
    let timeout;
    return function (...args) {
      const context = this;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait);
    };
  }

  // Function to update board title on the server
  async function updateBoardTitle(boardId, newTitle) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/kanban/update-board-title', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ boardId, newTitle })
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Error updating board title');
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      showNotification('success', 'Board updated successfully', 5000);
    } catch (error) {
      showNotification('danger', 'Error updating board title', 5000);
    }
  }

  // Delete board for rendered boards
  const deleteBoards = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-board'));
  if (deleteBoards) {
    deleteBoards.forEach(function (elem) {
      elem.addEventListener('click', async function () {
        const id = this.closest('.kanban-board').getAttribute('data-id');
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`/kanban/delete-board/${id}`, { method: 'DELETE' });
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Error removing board');
          }
          const data = await response.json();
          kanban.removeBoard(id);
          showNotification('success', 'Board removed successfully', 5000);
        } catch (error) {
          showNotification('danger', 'Error removing board', 5000);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Delete task for rendered boards
  const deleteTask = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-task'));
  if (deleteTask) {
    deleteTask.forEach(function (e) {
      e.addEventListener('click', async function () {
        const id = this.closest('.kanban-item').getAttribute('data-eid');
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`/kanban/delete-task/${id}`, { method: 'DELETE' });
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Error removing task');
          }
          const data = await response.json();
          kanban.removeElement(id);
          showNotification('success', 'Task removed successfully', 5000);
        } catch (error) {
          showNotification('danger', 'Error removing task', 5000);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Clear comment editor on close
  kanbanSidebar.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function () {
    kanbanSidebar.querySelector('.ql-editor').firstElementChild.innerHTML = '';
  });

  // Reinitialize tooltip when offcanvas opens (Bootstrap bug)
  if (kanbanSidebar) {
    kanbanSidebar.addEventListener('shown.bs.offcanvas', function () {
      const tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(kanbanSidebar.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
      tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
      });
    });
  }

  // Add subtle button to create new column at the end of columns
  const addColumnButton = document.createElement('button');
  addColumnButton.textContent = '➕';
  addColumnButton.className = 'kanban-title-button btn btn-default text-heading fw-normal shadow-none text-capitalize';
  addColumnButton.style.margin = '10px'; // Margin adjustment for better positioning

  // Add the button to the end of the Kanban container
  kanbanContainer.appendChild(addColumnButton);

  addColumnButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    showNotification('warning', 'Add a task to complete column creation!', 6000);
    const newBoardId = `board-${Date.now()}`; // Unique ID for the new column
    const newBoard = {
      id: newBoardId,
      title: ' Waiting for 1 Task',
      item: []
    };

    kanban.addBoards([newBoard]);

    // Reposition the button after the new column
    kanbanContainer.appendChild(addColumnButton);
  });

  if (kanbanTitleBoard) {
    kanbanTitleBoard.forEach(function (elem) {
      // Add double-click event to start editing
      elem.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
        const currentTitle = this.textContent;
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.value = currentTitle;
        input.className = 'form-control';

        // Replace title with input field
        this.textContent = '';
        this.appendChild(input);

        // Focus on input field
        input.focus();

        // When user leaves input field, update title
        input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
          const newTitle = input.value.trim();
          const boardId = elem.closest('.kanban-board').getAttribute('data-id');
          if (newTitle && newTitle !== currentTitle) {
            elem.textContent = newTitle;
            updateBoardTitle(boardId, newTitle);
          } else {
            elem.textContent = currentTitle; // Keep original title
          }
        });

        // Update title on Enter key press
        input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
          if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            input.blur();
          }
        });
      });

      elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', renderBoardDropdown());
    });
  }

})();

What could be causing the duplication of click events, even after removing the existing event before adding a new one? Is there a more effective way to ensure the click event is registered only once?
I appreciate any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue!

Can you please remove all the unnecessary code and just put the relevant code for users to understand better?

Where exactly are you calling removeEventListener?
